# Calculate rating based on different parameters

Tags: score

I want to predict the rating of an area based on different parameter like crime rate, number of malls, number of hospitals etc. There is no historical data available, so I don't have any training data for this.

There are two scenarios:

1. Each parameter has same weighting.
2. Each parameter has different weighting.

How can I calculate this?